# Installing gold linker on OS X

Tags: macos, linker, homebrew

i'm trying to get gold linker on OS X. I tried both brew install binutils (works but there is no gold linker) and install from git head (fails).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gold is an [ELF-only linker](https://sourceware.org/ml/binutils/2008-03/msg00162.html). OS X does [*not*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach-O) use ELF.

If you are cross-compiling, you probably want to use [lld](https://lld.llvm.org/) instead.

Comment: Sure, but he could be trying to cross-compile for a platform that does use ELF.

That's what I'm trying to do. I found this answer as the top google result, it isn't helpful!

Comment: @DisplayName Instead of complaining here, you should ask a separate question since *your* details are *different* from this question.

Comment: @EmployedRussian The OP didn't specify what they were using it for. They  merely asked the question of how to install it on macos.

Comment: The OP wasn't asking if the gold linker worked on OSX, he was asking how to install it. I, too, came here looking for a way to install ld.gold on OSX for a cross-compilation solution.